# How set the query in array values

Tags: php, php-5.6

Here i am using search form , i have two foem fields one normal field second one is array values,i want set query like this

```
SELECT * FROM commercial_office_space 
WHERE area='1' AND propertyType='6' OR propertyType='8'
```

so i am trying like this but i am not able to set the correct i am getting like this

```
SELECT * FROM commercial_office_space 
WHERE area='1' AND (propertyType='6')
```

i am using foreach loop but this is always taken the last values only i don;t know how to fix this issue

```
$areaName = trim($_GET['areaName']); 
$response = Array 
( 
"0" => "2" ,
"1" =>  "4" ,
"2" =>  "6" 
)  ;
foreach($response as $key => $value){
     $value;
}
$query="SELECT * FROM commercial_office_space WHERE area='1'";

if($response!='')
{
    echo $query.=" AND (propertyType='$value')"; // SELECT * FROM commercial_office_space WHERE area='1' AND (propertyType='6')
}
```

Comment: Why are you doing `echo` instead of assigning? Also, this is not how to build database queries. Look up prepared statements and [parameterized queries](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/php/5828/pdo/2685/preventing-sql-injection-with-parameterized-queries#t=201701272020064242131).

Comment: Really I think you just need to sit down with a PHP manual or a book or a few tutorials. Or all of the above

Comment: You aren't _using_ a `foreach` loop. What is happening inside that loop? Nothing.

Comment: How can set query like my requirement?

Comment: By starting at the beginning which means learning some basic PHP before attempting any more coding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the sql "IN" command. Build your array any way you'd like and use it like this:

```
$property_types = array('6', '8');

$sql = "SELECT * FROM commercial_office_space WHERE area='1' AND propertyType IN ( '" . implode($property_types, "', '") . "' )";
```

Comment: Thanks Mr Dan Weber

Comment: You're very welcome. Best of luck in your programming endeavors.